# PDO Like Condition, Make UPPERCASE Match

Tags: php, pdo, xampp

I am trying to use PDO LIKE condition to get the corresponding values from the database. Now the problem is some values in the database start with UPPERCASE. I am trying to query the database with the column values UPPERCASED.

If I use this code:

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM ingredient WHERE name LIKE ?');
    $query = '%'.$queryEntered.'%';
    $stmt -> execute(array($query));
```

I do get results and I would prefer to have something along the lines of

```
$query = $queryEntered.'%';
    $stmt -> execute(array($query));
```

I just cant seem to get the data in the column to bed UPPERCASED so there is never a match.
Been searching for a while. Any help would be nice.

Comment: would `SELECT * FROM ingredient WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE ?` work?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what character set and collation you are using. Most MySQL installations default to latin1_swedish_ci which has case insensitive string comparisons. You could try to force a case sensitive comparison.

```
'SELECT * FROM ingredient WHERE name COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE ?'
```

Also see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: case insensitive would be ok and I just verified it is latin1_swedish_ci. I just dont understand why I dont get results when I change the query value to "value%" and not "%value%"

Comment: Could you post an example of your input (queryEntered) and your data (queried table)? I'm not 100% sure if I understand your problem.